# Cannot delete document from local.system.replset when authentication enabled

Tags: mongodb, replicaset

I have MongoDB replica set with enabled authentication. I want to change replica set name. In order to do that I have to delete documents from `local.system.replset` collection. I have admin user with  `root@admin` role assigned, also I have regular user with `readWrite@local` role. When I try to execute `remove` from  the shell with any of the users above I get `Unauthorized` exception:

```
> db.system.replset.remove({})
WriteCommandError({
        "operationTime" : Timestamp(1582026365, 1),
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "not authorized on local to execute command { delete: \"system.replset\", ordered: true, lsid: { id: UUID(\"43182bad-b13d-4ff4-a31b-3cdcb1dd49fa\") }, $clusterTime: { clusterTime: Timestamp(1582026355, 1), signature: { hash: BinData(0, E9FD8A23702CE215B193423CAF1C2AF3FEE83D6B), keyId: 6794747247067136002 } }, $db: \"local\" }",
        "code" : 13,
        "codeName" : "Unauthorized",
        "$clusterTime" : {
                "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1582026365, 1),
                "signature" : {
                        "hash" : BinData(0,"CyCvFtgLkpdhIrsJV67KBlVwL+U="),
                        "keyId" : NumberLong("6794747247067136002")
                }
        }
})
```

If I try to execute same command on replica set with no authentication enabled I can successfully remove the record. What role am I missing on order to let user to delete record from `local.system.replset`? Or is it not supported when authentication is enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20120639/2138959 gave me a hint that `root` user may not have the privileges required and indeed it only has `find` privilege. I still don't know why `readWrite@local` didn't allow to write to `system.replicaset`, but when I added new role with `find`, `insert`, `remove`, `update`, `bypassDocumentValidation`, `useUUID` privileges for `local.system.replset` resource I was able to finally remove the replica set and update the name.

Another even simpler option is to assign `dbOwner@local` role to the user.

Comment: Same problem here, local DB is not allowed to create any custom roles. But we can create roles in admin DB for local DB.

Answer (score 1):

Both `root` and `dbOwner@local` do have general privileges to the database:

```
> db.getRole( "dbOwner", { showPrivileges: true } )
{
    "role" : "dbOwner",
    "db" : "local",
    "isBuiltin" : true,
    "roles" : [ ],
    "inheritedRoles" : [ ],
    "privileges" : [
        {
            "resource" : {
                **"db" : "local",
                "collection" : ""**
            },
(...)
```

But, quoting [the documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/resource-document/#specify-a-database-as-resource):

> If only the collection field is an empty string (""), the resource is
> the specified database, **excluding the system collections**.

Therefore, in order to get write access to the `system.replicaset`, you need to add a role specifically for this collection:

`> db.createRole( { role: "rs_admin",  privileges: [ { resource: { db: "local", collection: "system.replset" }, actions: [ "find", "insert", "remove" ] } ], roles: [] } )`